# Jquery change function not working for page size change in jqgrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, pagination

I have try to use below code but it not working :

```
$('.ui-pg-selbox').change(function(){
alert('Test');

})
```

Here is html which has shown on the browser :

```
<select class="ui-pg-selbox" role="listbox"><option role="option" value="10" selected="selected">10</option><option role="option" value="20">20</option><option role="option" value="30">30</option></select>
```

Comment: I don't see the problem, tried your code and it worked: (https://jsfiddle.net/_Sascha_/h6jr3Lrk/) Is jQuery really loaded? (what returns your Console?)

Comment: your given example also not working .. https://jsfiddle.net/_Sascha_/h6jr3Lrk/

Comment: it works , what exaclty you need

Comment: Yes its working... thanks

Comment: is this html code (<select class="ui-pg-selbox" ....)populated on runtime or it is on the html page?